# How can I sign by privatekey1 but sendrawtransaction by privatekey2?

Tags: ether

Whether I can sign the tx by private key 1 but I use private key 2 to sendrawtransaction, any sample code for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing `sendrawtransaction`.

There is [signTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction), which returns a raw (signed) transaction.

You obviously don't need a private key at this point, since this raw transaction has already been signed; you can send it as is via [sendSignedTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#eth-sendsignedtransaction).

Comment: Thanks
if I sendsignedtransaction, which account will pay the gas, account1 sign this transaction but account2 run sendsignedtransaction, whether account2 will pay gas? So I can let account1 sign but let account2 sendsignedtransaction so account2 will pay the gas?
Thank you.

Comment: @Louis: Account1 will pay for it. And what do you mean "Account2 run sendsignedtransaction"? If the private key of Account1 is used, then this IS the account which executes the transaction (in the contract, `msg.sender` will be the address of Account1).

Comment: Thanks but if account1 has no ether inside whether account2 can pay the gas for account1?

Comment: @Louis: You can transfer ether from Account2 to Account1 before initiating the transaction.

Comment: Actually I am thinking if I want to transfer usdt from account1 to account2, but account1 has no ether, then whether another account can pay for the gas? How to do this?

Comment: Thinking whether it is possible to pay gas by another account in case there is no ether in account1, if transfer a small amount from account2 and then start the transaction, after transfer the token from account1 to account2, there should be some small amount left on account1, it will be hard to transfer this small amount back.

Comment: @Louis: **You cannot initiate a transaction from an account without having ether in that account**. I'm pretty sure that you've been explained that in several previous questions of yours (in some cases, I even recall being the one doing the explanation).

Comment: Thanks that means I have to put a small amount in account1 and then transfer the usdt from accoun1 to account2, account1 pay the gas and after the transaction, account1 will transfer the left eth back to accout2， correct? Any way to ensure all the left small amount of eth on account1 will be transferred back? This need some calculation like 21000*gasprice...?

Comment: @Louis: Yes. Keep in mind that you can transfer only what is left in account1 minus `21000*gasprice`... And I now see that you've mentioned that.

Comment: Thanks, I am thinking whether we can use multi sign to let another account to pay for gas? I remembered somebody mentioned relay some where but I cannot find the post.

Comment: @Louis: If it has answered you question, then you can click on the V next to it.

Comment: Actually I did not see the V, only the triangle on the left as vote

Comment: @Louis: There is a V right below these two triangles.